# Modification to J48 Algorithm in Weka

Tags: weka

I would like to modify Weka's J48 algorithm in this way:

I would like to change the J48 algorithm to divide the data similar to the RandomForest algorithm( the code responsible for finding the best split in node).

What I have to do?  I know that I have to change the part of C45ModelSelection code for code in RandomForest:

```
C45ModelSelection.java

... 

  // Find "best" attribute to split on.
  minResult = 0;
  for (i=0;i<data.numAttributes();i++){
if ((i != (data).classIndex()) &&
    (currentModel[i].checkModel()))

  // Use 1E-3 here to get a closer approximation to the original
  // implementation.
  if ((currentModel[i].infoGain() >= (averageInfoGain-1E-3)) &&
      Utils.gr(currentModel[i].gainRatio(),minResult)){ 
    bestModel = currentModel[i];
    minResult = currentModel[i].gainRatio();
  } 
  }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking to replace the Split code with the RandomForest Split Code.  This code appears to exist in RandomTree.buildTree function in RandomTree.java

The split code appears somewhat different to the J48 Code, so you may need to consider what other changes are required in addition to the split code for the functionality to work correctly, but this would be a good starting point for achieving what you are after.

Hope this Helps!